# How to fix Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO), Laravel Homestead?

Tags: mysql, xampp, laravel-5.1, homestead

I use `laravel 5.1` homestead. I wanna connect to and show data from `mysql  (xampp)`. But I got this error :

[image]

this is my **.env setting** :

`DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel5
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate user in your mysql-server using your phpmyadmin and set a password for that specific user or you could simply set a password for your root account

[image: Example]

Comment: I have attached a screenshot from phpmyadmin, you should click on users on the upper navigation bar, and then click on edit privileges for root localhost

Comment: Did you set a password for root?

Comment: Hi, Robery. I can't access phpmyadmin again.. How to make it like before.

Comment: well, if you set a password for the root @ localhost, you will be prompted to login into your phpmyadmin providing the username: root and the password that you have chosen

Answer (score 0):

Access denied mysql error could be one of these 2 options:

option 1: invalid password, so check if root user has password or not

option 2: user grants, it means even though the password is correct, you haven't set proper **grants** to allow that specific user to connect from your local machine or a remote machine.

Try this: set a password for root user and then, edit privileges to allow connecting from any host (using % as host)

Comment: how to allow the spesific user to connect from my local mechine?

Comment: when you add grants for user root, set as host "localhost", also add another entry with "127.0.0.1"

Comment: Did you set the password to root user?
By the way, how did you add the grants? because if you are using command line tools, you MUST execute `flush privileges;` mysql command